# Need help toggling .prop() to true and false using .toggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery

As stated on the title I am trying toggle the input element properties to true and false for a click event, but having a hard time figuring this one out. This is what I have for now... Any help would be really appreciated!!!! Thank you!!

```
 $("#sign_in_link, #create_account_link").on("click", function(){


          //Hide the sign in link and show the create account link
        $("#sign_in_link").toggle(0, function(){
            $("#create_account_link").toggle();


        });
        $("#create_account").toggle(0, function(){

        // Need help with this
            $("#sign_in_link").toggle(0, function(){
            $("#create_account_link").toggle();

        });

        var link_type = $(this);


        $("#create_account").toggle(0, function(link_type){

           console.log(link_type)  //For some reason link_type is undefined??



            if(link_type == "#sign_in_link") {
                $("#new_acc_email").prop({disabled: true});// Link
                $("#new_acc_pw").prop({disabled: true});// Link
            }else{
                $("#new_acc_email").prop({disabled: false});// Link
                $("#new_acc_pw").prop({disabled: false});// Link
            }
        });//Div Container

        return false;



    });
```

Comment: Specifically, how is it not working? Do you get any errors or warnings in the editor console?

Comment: why are you using `.toggle(0,...`????

Comment: @BhojendraNepal . Because I don't want any kind of animations

Comment: @Chris It show the variable as undefined..

Answer (score 0):

Never mind guys!! I figured it out.. here is what I did

```
    $("#create_account").toggle(0, function(){



            $("#new_acc_email").prop({disabled: true});// Link
            $("#new_acc_pw").prop({disabled: true});// Link



    },function(){
        $("#new_acc_email").prop({disabled: false});// Link
        $("#new_acc_pw").prop({disabled: false});// Link
```